# wrapped captcha control in a p tag, how to shift it to the right?

Tags: html, css, captcha

wrapped captcha control in a p tag, how to shift it to the right about 50 px?

**Edit**
I am using reCaptcha using the .net control.  My input elements are to the right of the page by about 50 px.

My repactha is rendering left aligned (all the way to the left, so the alignment is off when compared to my other input fields).

Answer (score 2):

```
#foo { margin-left: 50px }
```

general question, general answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the style to a 50 pixel padding?

```
<p style="padding-left: 50px;"> ... </p>
```

If that doesn't work, you can always isert a 50 pixel image before the control.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague. I suppose the captcha is implemented using an image. In that case you could use CSS.

```
#captcha {
    position:relative;
    left:50px; /* moves the element 50px to the right */
}
```